# How can I close a python socket server from outside the function

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to create a socket server. It works as follows:

First, the user is given an entry widget. If he enters "start server", then the server will be started. If the user enters "end server", then the current connection should be closed.

However, the closing has to be done outside of the `console_win` function and I don't know how to do that.

```py
from tkinter import *
import socket
from tkinter import messagebox
import threading
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

# configurations
bg_color = "#2A2A2A"
frame_bg_color = "#1F1F1F"
label_fg_color = "cyan"
btn_fg_color = "cyan"
btn_bg_color = "#1F1F1F"
entry_bg_color = "#1F1F1F"
entry_fg_color = "red"

def backdoor_winfunc():
    def on_enter(e):
        e.widget["foreground"] = "#fb1466"

    def on_leave(e):
        e.widget["foreground"] = "cyan"

    def connect_internet():
        try:
            sock = socket.create_connection(("www.google.com", 80))
            if sock is not None:
                sock.close
                return True

        except OSError:
            return False

    def console_win():
        # function

        def create_server():
            global s
            ip = bck_ip_var.get()
            port = bck_port_var.get()

            if "." not in ip:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Invalid ip address!")
                return False

            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.bind((ip, port))
            # print(f"Binded to {ip}:{port}")
            console_box.insert(END, f"[+] Server Started at {ip}:{port}!")
            s.listen(1)
            while True:
                conn, addr = s.accept()
                console_box.insert(END, f"Connected to {addr}!")
                while conn:
                    data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
                    if data == "end":
                        conn.close()

        def take_cmd(e):
            cmd = cmd_box_var.get()

            if cmd == "help":
                console_box.config(fg="red")
                console_box.config(fg="lime")
                with open("Assets\\cmd_files\\help.txt", "r") as rw:
                    help_data = rw.read()
                    console_box.insert(END, help_data)
                    console_box.insert(END, "\n")
                    console_box.insert(END, "\n")

            elif cmd == "clear":
                console_box.delete("1.0", END)

            elif cmd == "start server":
                t1 = threading.Thread(target=create_server)
                t1.start()

            else:
                console_box.insert(
                    END,
                    "\n[-] Invalid command! please check our help menu using command 'help'\n",
                )

        # check internet connection
        is_internet = connect_internet()
        if is_internet == False:
            messagebox.showerror(
                "Error", "Oops! Its look like you are not connected to internet"
            )
            return False

        # configurations
        console_win = Toplevel()
        console_win.geometry("800x605+200+50")
        console_win.title("Console")
        console_win.config(bg="#252525")

        scrl_bar = Scrollbar(console_win, width=20)
        scrl_bar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        console_box = Text(
            console_win,
            height=19,
            width=60,
            bg=frame_bg_color,
            state="normal",
            yscrollcommand=scrl_bar.set,
            font=("Arial"),
            fg="lime",
        )
        console_box.pack()

        scrl_bar.config(command=console_box.yview)

        cmd_box_var = StringVar(value="start server")

        command_box = Entry(
            console_win,
            font=("Arial 30"),
            textvariable=cmd_box_var,
            bg=bg_color,
            fg="cyan",
            width=30,
        )
        command_box.focus()
        command_box.bind("<Return>", take_cmd)
        command_box.setvar("start server")
        command_box.pack(pady=(10, 0))

        console_win.mainloop()

    backdoorwin = Tk()
    backdoorwin.config(bg=bg_color)
    backdoorwin.title("Backdoor")
    backdoorwin.geometry("800x600+200+50")
    # frame
    backdoor_f = Frame(backdoorwin, bg=frame_bg_color)
    backdoor_f.pack(pady=120)
    # header
    img = Image.open("Assets\images\death.png")
    img = img.resize((100, 100))
    logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    logo_lb = Label(backdoor_f, image=logo, bg=frame_bg_color)
    logo_lb.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(15, 15))
    bck_logo_txt = Label(
        backdoor_f,
        text="BACKDOOR",
        fg="#fb1466",
        bg=frame_bg_color,
        font=("sarif 40 bold"),
    )
    bck_logo_txt.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=(15, 0), padx=(0, 0))

    # variables
    bck_ip_var = StringVar(value=socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
    bck_port_var = IntVar(value=8080)

    # label
    bck_ip_lb = Label(
        backdoor_f,
        text="Ip Address",
        font=("sarif 20 bold"),
        bg=frame_bg_color,
        fg=label_fg_color,
    )
    bck_ip_lb.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(60, 30), pady=(0, 0))
    bck_port_lb = Label(
        backdoor_f,
        text="Port",
        font=("sarif 20 bold"),
        bg=frame_bg_color,
        fg=label_fg_color,
    )
    bck_port_lb.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=(60, 30), pady=(15, 15))
    # entry
    bck_ip_en = Entry(
        backdoor_f,
        textvariable=bck_ip_var,
        font=("san-sarif 20"),
        bg=entry_bg_color,
        fg=entry_fg_color,
        justify="center",
    )
    bck_ip_en.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(0, 30), pady=(0, 0))

    bck_port_en = Entry(
        backdoor_f,
        textvariable=bck_port_var,
        font=("san-sarif 20"),
        bg=entry_bg_color,
        fg=entry_fg_color,
        justify="center",
    )
    bck_port_en.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=(0, 30), pady=(15, 15))

    # button
    cr_backdoor_btn = Button(
        backdoor_f,
        text="Host",
        font=("sarif 20 bold"),
        bg=btn_bg_color,
        fg=btn_fg_color,
        cursor="hand2",
        command=lambda: console_win(),
    )
    cr_backdoor_btn.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=(0, 70))
    # btnconfig
    cr_backdoor_btn.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
    cr_backdoor_btn.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)
    backdoorwin.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    backdoor_winfunc()
```

Comment: Could you [edit] some more information about your problem into your post? If you do get any errors, than please include them, including their traceback, into your post. Otherwise, explain clearly why the given code doesn't work.

Comment: i have edited it. now you can see the full code

Comment: Thank you for the full code! Still, it would be usefull if you explained more thoroughly what exactly the problem is. How does the code behave, what is wrong about it and how do you expect it to behave? Are there any errors?

Comment: Thank you for the new information! I think it will definetely help other users with finding the correct answer. I've [edit]ed it in your post. If any of the text in your post is incorrect, feel free to change it. (It might take a while before the edit becomes visible to you.

Answer (score 1):

Given the information in your post, it is unclear how the rest of your code is structured and how you plan to use these functions. However, I can give a general way to do what I'm assuming you're trying to achieve.

Perhaps the simplest way to do this is to create your socket from a new thread, then terminate that thread from the `close_socket` function. Here's an example of how you might implement this (untested):

```
import threading

def create_server(address: str, port: int, close_event: threading.Event):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((address, port))
    s.listen(5)
    while not close_event.is_set():
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print("connected!")
        while conn:
            data = conn.revc(1024).decode()
            if data == "end":
                conn.close()
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    s.close()

def close_socket(close_event: threading.Event):
    close_event.set()


server_close_event = threading.Event()
server_thread = threading.Thread(target=create_server, args=("", 8080, server_close_event)).start()

# later when you want to stop the server thread
close_socket(server_close_event)
server_thread.join()
```

There are other ways to achieve the same effect, but any time you want something running in an infinite loop, but not blocking the main program's execution, a thread is usually a good place to start. I usually organize this using a simple class with a `start`, `stop`, and `_stream` method, where `start` calls `_stream` in a separate thread, and `stop` triggers some side effect that breaks the `while` loop.

Also, it is not clear what the server socket in the example you provided is intended to do (or if it will work the way you are intending), but given that the question is specifically asking about stopping the server, I simply used your code as is.

Answer (score -1):

To close the socket outside the console_win function, you need to be able to access your variable outside the function scope or pass it as an argument to called function.

Please note, I'm talking about closing socket and not a connection. As it is what I understand you asked. It would also be better if you could explain precisely what you want to do, especially if I did not understand what you wanted.

Assuming you want to close the socket from a function that got called by the connection data processing, you probably just need to pass the socket as an argument.

```
            if data == "other":
                #this function may close the socket (and we assume need data)
                callAnotherFunction(data,s)
                ...
```

with `s.close()` somewhere in "callAnotherFunction".

You can also return true if the socket should be closed

```
            if data == "other":
                #this function may want to close the socket
                result = callAnotherFunction(data)
                if(result):
                    s.close()
                    ...
```

If you need to close the socket from an function before console_win,
You can pass console_win an argument to store the socket.
For example, assuming "socketList" an 1 element mutable list (1 element python default list)

```
def console_win(socketList):
    #function

    def create_server(socketList):
        global conn
        ...
        #later in the function
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        socketList[0] = s
        ...
    
    #later in the function, when create_server is called
    create_server(socketList)
```

and for the function that called console_win can look like this:

```
def exempleFunction():
    ...
    #prepare the list
    socketList = [None]
    #call console_win (called from another thread before to avoid being lock by s.accept() and the while loop)
    console_win(socketList)
    ...
    #later when you want to close the socket
    socketList[0].close()
```

Or you can use a global variable.

```
def console_win():
    #function

    def create_server():
        global conn, s
        ...
```

And can be close almost anywhere with

```
global s
s.close()
```

Please note global variable cause namespace pollution.
Also, in those 2 last case I recommend learning how to use thread to call your function console_win in a new thread. There is a lot of online documentation about it.

Comment: If you don't understand the question then it's best to avoid attempting to answer it.